# Not able to connect through browser port 8080

Tags: amazon-ec2

I launched a Amazon EC2 t1.micro Free usage tier instance. After creating a private key-pair I did following on my mac (local machine)

```
ec2-authorize default -p 22
ec2-authorize default -p 8080
ec2-authorize default -p 80
```

But I am not able to connect to port 80 or 8080. Connection timed out error.

On port 8080, I run mulgara RDFStore. I access using http://$publicDNSName:8080

my .profile looks like:

```
export EC2_HOME=~/.ec2
export PATH=$PATH:$EC2_HOME/bin
export EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=pk-MYKEYNAME.pem
export EC2_CERT=cert-MYKEYNAME.pem
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/
```

Please help

Comment: I did on my EC2 instance:

sudo yum -y install httpd
sudo /sbin/chkconfig httpd on
sudo /sbin/service httpd start

On my MAC (localhost - not EC2 instance)

ec2-authorize default -p 80

Still no success

Comment: Not sure how this was off topic as EC2 is a framework/infrastructure and my question was tagged and relevant in the context of EC2 framework. In amazon-ec2 category/tag of stackoverflow, not every question can be programming related. But anyways I will take the negative votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. Fixed the problem. I was allowing access to default security group. Instead I should have used the group created by AWS at launch

Thanks!!